# Поиск в базе данных sqlite

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, sqlite

Есть база данных sqlite подключенная через DataGridView.
Надо реализовать поиск,то есть, я ввожу название товара  в textbox,нажимаю кнопку поиск,и он мне выводит данный товар в DataGridView.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbFileName + ";Version=3;");
    m_dbConn.Open();
    m_sqlCmd.Connection = m_dbConn;

    string query = "SELECT '" + textBox1.Text + "' FROM tovari";

    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, m_dbConn);

    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        data.Add(new string[5]);

        data[data.Count - 1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
        data[data.Count - 1][1] = reader[1].ToString();
        data[data.Count - 1][2] = reader[2].ToString();
        data[data.Count - 1][3] = reader[3].ToString();
        data[data.Count - 1][4] = reader[4].ToString();

    }

    reader.Close();

    m_dbConn.Close();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    foreach (string[] s in data)
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);
}
```

После нажатия на кнопку поиска крашится,выдавая-
 System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."

Comment: Чему равно содержимое `textBox1.Text` в момент запроса? Там пять значений, разделённых запятыми?

Comment: Скажу подсказку в режиме экстрасенса - делайте "SELECT * FROM tovari WHERE tovari.имяполя LIKE '%"+textBox1.Text+"'";

Comment: Канал связи с информационным биополем нестабильный, информацию, всё таки, надо перепроверить. Поэтому подробнее опишите таблицу - названия полей, их типы...

Comment: Советую почитать про DataSet. Они позволят не писать самому строки подключения и получения данных а написать процедуру или запрос и загнать результат в DataTable который легко разбирается. Будет что то следующее:
`var Data = new GetNamesTableAdapter().GetData();
foreach  (var Item in Data)
{ ... }` Метод getnames это будет ваш запрос. И таких исключений как у вас не будет)

Answer (score 1):

Попробую предположить, что sql запрос на поиск записи составлен не правильно.
Попробуйте такой вариант запроса:

```
"select * from tovari where [ИмяПоля] like '%" + TextBox.Text + "%'"
```